# Retinex implementation python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, image-enhancement

I am not really new to python programming, but I am just confused about implementing fundamental retinex (Single Scale Retinex).
I know the Retinex formula : **retinex = logI(x,y) - (log(F(x,y)) * I(x,y))** and
here is my code:

```
def singleScaleRetinex(img, sigma):
    retinex = np.log10(img) - np.log10(cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (0,0), sigma))
return retinex
```

After running my code for single scale output image was almost going to dark just like edge detection.
I did on a higher scale and lower scale, but the same output.

**Can you help my problem ?

is the code wrong ?**

add some question:
we now that

```
logR(x,y) = LogI(x,y) - Log[G(x,y)*I(x,y)]
```

but why **R(x,y) = LogR(x,y) ?** (explain me)

[image: here is my output]

Comment: What did you expect as output? If you take the log of the image, you’ll have lower values. If you then subtract the local mean, you’ll have even lower values.

Comment: I expected that output of single scale retinex were better than original image.

Comment: It solved anyway.